# can i search in itemsource and bind again to listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listview

i have listview and textbox for search in listview every time user type in textbox i run new query, is there any better way to do that?without running query from database just from itemsources?

```
private void txtEditSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtEditSearch.Text != string.Empty)
    {
         var query = GetAllSchoolsAsync(txtEditSearch.Text);
         query.Wait();

         List<DataClass.Tables.School> data = query.Result;
         if (data.Any())
              dgv.ItemsSource = data;
     }
     else
        getSchool();
}
```

i need something like this:

```
var basedata = dgv.Itemsource;
dgv.ItemSource = basedata.where(x=>x.Name == txtEditSearch.Text).Select(x=>x);
```

Comment: Why you don't query all records from your database once ? And then you execute your filter on this source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way, I recommend you, to achieve this is creating an initial unfiltered collection and filter from this collection.

Make a private field to store the initial School items:

```cs
private List<DataClass.Tables.School> _initialCollection;
```

Fill it with the unfiltered items in the contructor:

```cs
public MyView()
{
  var query = GetAllSchoolsAsync();
  query.Wait();
  _initialCollection = query.Result;      
}
```

In the TextChanged eventhandler you can add the filtering to theItemSource of the ListView:

```cs
private void txtEditSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  dgv.ItemSource = _initialCollection.Where(x=>x.Name == txtEditSearch.Text).Select(x=>x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the listview is populated with data you can filter on that data which acts just like a search, just displays the data you asked for. Here is the link I learnt about this from:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/